# I want to make a function that takes a sentence and returns a list the longest word along with words that have the same length of the longest word

Tags: python, list

The code below only splits the string into a list and selects the longest word of list. But now I also want to append words of the same length of the longest word. For example, if the input was "me dog cat" the output should be ['dog', 'cat'].

```
def longest_wordlist(string):
    string = string.split()
    longest = ''
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if len(string[i]) > len(string[i-1]):
            longest = string[i]
    return longest
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can also do the samething without using range function.

```
def longest_wordlist(string):
    string = string.split()
    longest = []
    longest_length = 0
    for word in string:
        if len(word)>longest_length:
            longest_length=len(word)
            longest=[word]
        elif len(word)==longest_length:
            longest.append(word)
    return longest
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple if condition first check for longer case second one is for the same length

```
def longest_wordlist(string):
    string = string.split()
    longest = []
    longest_length = 0
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if len(string[i]) > longest_length:
            longest = [string[i]]
            longest_length = len(string[i])
        elif len(string[i]) == longest_length:
            longest.append(string[i])
    return longest
```

The result

```
>>> longest_wordlist("me dog cat")
['dog', 'cat']
```